# PIP: Force to install latest version of dependent library if there is a conflict

Tags: python, pip

I have upgrading a python project with lots of dependencies to the latest python version. While upgrading I am facing dependencies conflicts like one of the dependent libraries required library A in one version and another library required in another version. Is there a way in PIP to force install the latest version of the dependent library by ignoring the conflict?

Comment: Does `--no-deps` do the trick?

Comment: @FlyingTeller --no-deps completely ignoring dependent libraries, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea